# SPARQL Query: Filter instance/result

Tags: filter, rdf, sparql

I am new to SPARQLR query and need some help.

I have 2 classes named "Platform" and "Video_game".

The "Platform" class has 3 instances: Windows, Playstation_4 and Xbox_One.

The "Video_game" class also has 3 instances: Just_Cause_3, Battlefield_4 and Grand_Theft_Auto_5

I also have object property named "availableOn" to link "Platform" and "Video_game" class together.

Now, if I want to retrieve all video games and their respective platform, I would run this query:

```
SELECT ?Name ?Platform
WHERE { ?Name rdf:type vg:Video_game  ;
        vg:availableOn ?Platform .  }
```

That query can be run successfully. But now, I would like to use "FILTER" command to only show all the game but only on a particular platform. For example, only on "Windows".

How would I be able to FILTER the result? Do I need to add some data properties to use the FILTER command?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `<P>` be the URI for the windows platform.  Get the right value from your data.

Something like:

```
SELECT ?Name
WHERE { ?Name rdf:type vg:Video_game  ;
              vg:availableOn <P> .  }
```

You don't need a FILTER.
Or

```
SELECT ?Name ?Platform
WHERE { ?Name rdf:type vg:Video_game  ;
              vg:availableOn ?Platform . 
        FILTER(?Platform = <P>)
}
```

if you still want ?Platform in the results.